# How to turn off Facebook notifications on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, facebook

How to turn off Facebook notifications on Mac OS X Mountain Lion?

Comment: FYI you can turn off notifications from within Facebook by going to **Notification -> Settings -> Desktop and Mobile** (good for older OSX versions that don't have a Notifications Center)

Comment: I would add that @Yarin's answer is general, whereas the answer by Daniel Beck is specific to Mountain Lion (it does not work on El Capitan because the Notifications system preferences panel is completely different). Yarin's comment ought to be made into an answer, and should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 71):

Open *System Preferences*, select the *Notifications* preference pane at the top right, and disable it there.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: lol wow i don't have a notifications center on my macbook pro, its running 10.7 too...where did you get that from?

Comment: @AlanTuring This question is about *Mountain Lion*, i.e. 10.8.

Comment: well i'm blind lol damn.

Comment: Just for a reference, a solution (**for El Capitan**). If you click on the padlock in the address bar next to *http://www.facebook.com*, you can change the permissions of the site quickly. n.b you can change any permissions of a site even if its not a padlock, just click on the icon to the left of the address.

Answer (score 18):

If the above answer didn't work for you because Facebook was already disabled in System Preferences and you use Google Chrome, you may be mistaking Chrome's notifications as OS X notifications. You can disable Google Chrome Notifications by following the instructions [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3220216?hl=en)

1. In the upper right corner of the browser window, click the Chrome menu.
2. Click Settings > Show advanced settings.
3. In the "Privacy" section, click Content settings.
4. In the dialog that appears, go to "Notifications" and configure your desired settings

Comment: Thank you! I was mystified by this and didn't realize it could have been Chrome.

Comment: Turning off OS X notification for FB was obvious but this finally solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks Cory. Any knows of an equivalent solution for Firefox?

Answer (score 2):

**Option+Click** the Notification Center menu bar icon, it will turn grey when disabled
To re-enable Notifications, just option+click the menu bar icon again. It will turn black to signify that it’s active again.

If you’re less of a keyboard fan and more of a gestures person, you can also hush notifications directly from the panel itself.

Comment: The question was not about how to turn off all notifications.

Comment: @frandroid: Agreed (+1)...though it *does* get the job done.... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For El-Capitan:

press Ctrl+Space, type "Notifications", choose "Facebook"

Just select the top-left icon "None" instead of "Banners" or "Alerts"

[image: notification settings]