# Disable *other* Facebook notification 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mavericks, notifications

This differs from this question [How to turn off Facebook notifications on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/480958/how-to-turn-off-facebook-notifications-on-mac-os-x)

The notifications are different to the rounded banner alerts I get, and in fact, before I disabled the other rounded banners, I was getting TWO Facebook notifications for every alert.

Here's how the notifications I'm getting looks.

[image]

Note how it's different to the normal rounder banners you get in Mavericks, such as the prompt to update software (see below).

[image]

I have disabled Facebook in the notification centre, which got rid of the rounded banners.

[image]

I have also turned Do not disturb on!!

Comment: That doesn't look like an OS X notification - sure it's not Facebook itself, while your browser's open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notification in your picture is a Google Chrome notification. Those  notifications function separately from the native OS X notification system.

To change settings for Chrome notifications, enter `Chrome Settings` through the menu bar, the chrome menu icon, or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>. Scroll down to the `Privacy` section and click on `Content settings...`. Scroll to the `Notifications` section and you will be able to change the default settings for Chrome notifications as well as manage exceptions.

Below is an image showing the location of these settings
[image]

Comment: Yep, I had to both tick the 'Do not allow any site to show notifications' and also then remove Facebook from the exceptions list that it had added itself to.  THANK YOU!